# Ubuntu imagemagick C transparent background

Tags: c, ubuntu, imagemagick, transparent

hello i'm trying to create a png with transparent background using the C api of imagemagick. I'm working on macosx and this is what i wrote:

*UPDATED*
i have this function that create me new image:

```
Image *new_image(Image *composed_image, ImageInfo *composed_image_info){
  ExceptionInfo *exception; 
  MagickPixelPacket *background;

  // make it transparent
  background->red = QuantumRange;
  background->blue = QuantumRange;
  background->green = QuantumRange;
  background->opacity = QuantumRange;

  exception=AcquireExceptionInfo();
  composed_image = NewMagickImage(composed_image_info, WIDTH, HEIGHT, background);
  if (exception->severity != UndefinedException) CatchException(exception); 
  if (composed_image == (Image *) NULL)   printf("Errore composed \n");
  exception = DestroyExceptionInfo(exception); 

  WriteImage(composed_image_info, composed_image); 

  return composed_image;
}
```

then the main main:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
  int images_counter = argc-3;
  Image *images[images_counter], *composed_image;
  ImageInfo *composed_image_info;
  ExceptionInfo *exception;

  // create new blank image
  composed_image_info = CloneImageInfo((ImageInfo *) NULL);
  strcpy(composed_image_info->filename, argv[argc-2]);
  composed_image = new_image(composed_image, composed_image_info);
  strcpy(composed_image->filename, argv[argc-2]);

  // get all the images
  for(size_t i = 0; i < images_counter; ++i) images[i] = read_image(argv[i+1]);

  // build all the images together
  for(size_t i = 0; i < images_counter; ++i) build_image(images[i], composed_image);

  // write the image
  WriteImage(composed_image_info, composed_image);

  // close and return
  MagickCoreTerminus();
  return(0); 
}
```

on osx it works but when i try it on Ubuntu server the created image is with white background, am i doing something wrong?

thanks

Comment: Do you have the same version of ImageMagick on both machines?

Comment: Where are the 20+ lines before that set up your variables?

Comment: @dlemstra, actually i have new one on ubuntu: local machine: Version: ImageMagick 6.5.8-4 2009-12-15 Q16 [it works], remote machine: Version: ImageMagick 6.6.9-7 2012-08-17 Q16 [new one, doesn't works]

Comment: @dlemstra i've managed to have the same version in both machines but i have the same result, i don't think is a matter of version, any other ideas? thanks